Messed up with partition creating dual boot
I am new here!
I was setting up dual boot on my laptop, which already had Windows.
I first flashed the usb with Ububtu, then once I boot from usb with it, I starded the installer...
Dunno why the installer probably interrupt, so I had to start over again.
In the end it worked, I installed Ubuntu but there is a problem with my partitions; checking with fdisk i see, beside other partiotions for microsoft etc., I have two partitions for linux filesystem:
 /dev/nvme0n1p7 640614400  749608959 108994560    52G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p8 749608960  947814399 198205440  94.5G Linux filesystem
Now the problem is I would like to merge those partitions (52+94.5) all in one single partition, since the 52g partition is empty, but I really dunno how! Could you please help me? I Mean, since it's a delicate issue, I don't wanna risk to make errors, so I am asking here.
Thank you!
output df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            1560776      2448   1558328   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p8  96959820  20355696  71632604  23% /
tmpfs            7803872         0   7803872   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        12      5108   1% /run/lock
efivarfs             128        46        78  38% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme0n1p1    262144     33788    228356  13% /boot/efi
tmpfs            1560772       136   1560636   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p3 320022852 231321708  88701144  73% /media/strawberry/OS

It sounds like you did not install the OS correctly in the first place. This is based on the info in the question. What tool did you use to create the boot media for the Ubuntu OS install? What version of Ubuntu are you working with? https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview Two links for you to read.

Edit question and add the output of linux command 'df'' (disk free).

Hello! I am running the version Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and I create the boot media with Balena etcher, which has always been good for what I needed..

Basically you wish to combine your Ubuntu working partition with another aborted Ubuntu install partition with no data in it?
Messing with partitions is a high risk activity of breaking something and/or losing data so make sure everything is backed up.
I can think of two options: -

First:
If the two partitions are contiguous (next to each other) then you could delete the one that has no data in it and extend the other one using the space created from the deletion.
You can only do this if the partitions are not mounted so I would recommend using gparted (a graphical partition tool) on the Ubuntu installation media. You could go further and move partitions around but I would not recommend doing this.
Second:
If the two partitions are not contiguous (next to each other) then I would recommend moving your home directory (you haven't already got a separate home) to the unused defunct Ubuntu partition. You might like to re-initialise this first (using gparted again) then see link below for details of how to do this.
How to create a separate home partition after installing Ubuntu under single / partition
Good luck.

Hiii @david, I am sorry for the late reply, but I was in holidays and I just came back. So, here I am. Could you please tell me why you don't recommend the first procedure? Is it risky? Just ask because seems easier, and also the partition, checking in gparted, are contiguous. Also one of the two partition is the one I am using Ubuntu, so I should maybe use a Live USB disk in order to keep all the other partitions unmounted, and do the operation, correct?

The thing I was not recommending is anything that involves moving all the data in a partition. It is possible but more risky. I think the partitions are arranged as so --------[52G/0G][94G/20G]. So deleting 52G, gparted will have to move 20G of data to a new position. I suspect making the 52G partition /Home will involve moving much less. A separate home has other advantages such as multiple Ubuntu OS with common data. You can try either but just make sure you backup everything first. Yes, you cant move mounted partitions so do use the install media gparted to do this.

/dev/nvme0n1p7 640614400  749608959 108994560    52G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p8 749608960  947814399 198205440  94.5G Linux filesystem those are the two partitions. I messed up, are both file system, but I use only the 94 one. Is it ok if i keep like this then, and I format the 56G and I use it as separate as you said?
