How to allocate the unallocated spaces. when i try to allocate it shows unmount the space
I have deleted windows operating system and completely moved to ubuntu. I have around 400 gb of unallocated space. How to allocate it to ubuntu?

This question is similar to: How to resize partitions?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You cannot adjust normal partitions if they are mounted. Try and boot from your install media, run a partitioner such as 'sudo gparted' and go from there. Make sure everything is backed up before you proceed. Alternatively, you can create new partitions in the space (which will not be mounted) and adjust your /etc/fstab file accordingly from your Ubuntu to mount them.  Also see answer here  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1524804/messed-up-with-partition-creating-dual-boot/1525067#1525067 and follow further links.
